# quality Profiles are 'never' updated on Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

Can someone please help me to update the Quality Profiles in Sonarqube, currently updated column shows "Never", PFA screen shot. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The Sonar way profile is provided by a plugin. It will automatically be updated when a new version of the supplying plugin changes its definition.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I think you have the correct answer there.